# Running multiple queries in Oracle with ODP.Net

Tags: oracle, plsql, odp.net

I want to be able to run multiple queries in ODP.Net ending with a select statement. I am clearing, updating and then selecting from a table.

As an example:

```
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM StagingTable;

    INSERT INTO StagingTable (Col1,Col2,Col3)
    SELECT Value1,Value2,Value3
    FROM MainTable;

    UPDATE StagingTable
    SET Col1 = FUNCTION(Col1);
END;
/
SELECT * FROM StagingTable;
```

This works in SQL Developer but not ODP.Net. I get this error:

> ORA-06550: line 26, column 1:
>       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"

But if I remove the / I get:

> ORA-06550: line 27, column 1:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT"

Is what I want to do even possible? I don't want to do have to create a package and start creating types and so on. Ideally I want to do this via .Net.

Comment: You can't do it like that.  Either put everything in a stored proc and return the select as a cursor, or break into two executions.

Comment: As OldProgrammer suggests, you are using SQL*Plus syntax (the backslash) which is fine for SQL Developer and similar tools, but not for programmatic interfaces. You can call anonymous PLSQL from ODP.NET with bind variables. You can put the whole thing into one anonymous PL/SQL block and bind to a REF CURSOR at the end. Then fetch from it.

Comment: Here's some example code showing calling an anonymous plsql block from odp.net and then binding to a ref cursor: http://www.oracle.com/partners/campaign/o16odpnet-087852.html

Answer (score 0):

Unlike SQL Server with t-sql, oracle has two contexts, SQL Plus and PL/SQL (begin/end is an anonymous plsql block, where the select outside would be SQL Plus).  I have not yet figured out a way to return a set from a SQL Plus query after a plsql block has started.

However, you can certainly do all of that in a plsql block and return a ref cursor:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(
    @"
    declare
        localUseVar varchar(50);
    begin
        select dummy into localUseVar from dual;

        open :refcursor for
        select dummy, localUseVar FROM DUAL 
        where :fakeparam=:fakeparam;
        end;
    ");
cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.Parameters.Add("fakeparam", "fake");
cmd.Parameters.Add("refcursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

using (cmd.Connection = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/xe; PERSIST SECURITY INFO = True; USER ID = TEMPLATE; Password=password"))
{
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    Assert.IsTrue(reader.Read());
    Assert.AreEqual(reader[0], reader[1]);

}
```

More info here:
http://www.brothersincode.com/post/executing-SQL-Plus-Batches-from-Net.aspx

Your specific case would like something like:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(
@"
begin
    DELETE FROM StagingTable;

    INSERT INTO StagingTable (Col1,Col2,Col3)
    SELECT Value1,Value2,Value3
    FROM MainTable;

    UPDATE StagingTable
    SET Col1 = FUNCTION(Col1);

    open :refcursor for SELECT * FROM StagingTable;
end;
");
cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.Parameters.Add("refcursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

using (cmd.Connection = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/xe; PERSIST SECURITY INFO = True; USER ID = TEMPLATE; Password=password"))
{
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

}
```